# Proving $(0, \infty)$ is open

Tags: real-analysis

I know that for $ x \in (0, \infty)$, I have to find some r>0 such that $N_r (p) \subset (0, \infty)$. My intuitive understanding of this is that I need to find a some ball such that the ball is in the set.

So for $x \in (0, \infty)$, I guess this implies x >0. So I should choose $x-r<x<r-x$? I know showing $x > 0$ is the end goal but I'm not sure how to go about this.

Comment: If $x\in (0,\infty)$, $x>0$ by definition, so $x>x/2>0$. So show that $(x/2, 3x/2)\subset (0,\infty)$.

Comment: I'm sorry, but where did x/2 and 3x/2 come from? Also, if I tried the p-neighborhood method, could I say that $(x-r, x+r) \subset (0, \infty)$ and so it is an interior point? And since x could be any point then we have that the set is open?

Comment: An example: Take $6$ in $(0,\infty)$  then $6 \in (5,7) \subseteq (0,\infty)$. Take 0,000001, which interval should we choose now?

Comment: @Nikitau It's a very common technique in analysis. We're looking for some $r>0$ which is a positive number such that $(x-r,x+r)\subset (0,\infty)$. That $x>0\Rightarrow 2x>x>0\Rightarrow x>x/2>0$. So $x-x/2=x/2>0$ and $x+x/2=3x/2>0$. So choosing $r=x/2$ gives us the open ball.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every $x \in (0,\infty)$ you can choose $r_1=x>0$ or $r_2=\frac{x}{2}>0$, for example. Then,

$N_{r_1}(x) = (x-r_1,x+r_1) = (x-x, x+x) = (0,2x) \subset (0,\infty) $

and

$N_{r_2}(x) = (x-r_2,x+r_2) = (x-\frac{x}{2}, x+\frac{x}{2}) = (\frac{x}{2}, \frac{3x}{2}) \subset (0,\infty)$.

It works in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

If $x \in (0,\infty)$, pick any positive $r$ where $r < x$.

Then $0 < x-r < x < x+r < \infty$ implies $N_r(x) = (x-r, x+r) \subset (0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 0):

$x \in (0,\infty) \iff 0 <x $

$B (x,r) = (x-r,x+r) $

We want $(x-r,x+r) \subset (0,\infty) $.

$(x-r,x+r) \subset (0,\infty)\iff 0\le x-r <x+r <\infty $.

So the question becomes proving such an $r $ always exists for all $x > 0$.

Can we prove that?

An obvious candidate is $r=x $.  If $r=x $ then $B (x,r) = (x-r,x+r) =(0,2x)\subset (0,\infty) $.  So $x $ is interior point and $(0,\infty) $ is open.